# Sample Hellinger Distance is Negative

Tags: estimation, distance, hellinger

The Hellinger distance between a true density $f$ and an estimate $\hat f$ is defined as $$H(f,\hat f) = \sqrt{1 - \int \sqrt{\frac{\hat f(x)}{f(x)}}f(x)\ \mathrm dx}.$$
I estimate the Hellinger distance from the sample by $$\hat H(f, \hat f) = \sqrt{1 - m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^m\sqrt{\frac{\hat f(x_i)}{f(x_i)}}},$$
where $m$ is the sample size. But $m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^m\sqrt{\frac{\hat f(x_i)}{f(x_i)}}$ larger than $1$, so the part unter the square root is negative. Is there an explanation/solution to this problem?

Comment: Something makes me doubt your formula. Is that Hellinger distance? Hellinger distance is $2\sqrt{1-BC}$ where BC is _fidelity_ aka _Bhattacharyya coefficient_.

Comment: there are different conventions regarding the scaling factor (1 vs 0.5). most authors use – afaik – the version I posted (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance#Probability_theory_using_Lebesgue_measure)

Comment: Your problem seems to stem from using a bad approximation to the integral.  The solution is to compute the integral accurately, perhaps using numerical quadrature for the *entire* estimated density function, not just its values at the sample points.

Comment: well, I have $m = 500$ and the "sample" actually corresponds a partition of  $[-1,1]$ into 500 equally long subintervals (`seq(-1, 1, length.out = 500)` in R). Isn't that already integrating the entire estimated density function? (almost all the mass lies in $[-1,1]$).